# Flask: Passing data from AJAX to a render_template() call, redirecting/refreshing the page with parameters

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, redirect, flask

This issue comes down to the fact that I haven't yet figured out how to pass data from javascript to Flask/Python via AJAX in the right way.

I have built a Flask application that uses JsPsych as a javascript/front-end framework for an online experiment. jsPsych allows you to create a handler function, `on_finish()`, that executes once the experiment is finished.

I wanted my experiment's data to be stored on the backend, and that was supposed to be the end o the experiment. I created a function called `data_to_csv()` that was mounted to the url `/temp_storage`, that did this. Then I created another url endpoint for `/experiment_end`, which displays a simple html page stating that the experiment is over and data was saved.

```
    jsPsych.init({
        ...
        on_finish: function() {
          var subj_id = jsPsych.data.get().select('user_id').values[0];
          var test_trials_collection = jsPsych.data.get();

          var test_trial_json = test_trials_collection.json();
          $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/temp_storage",
            data: {experiment_data:test_trial_json, webapp_id:subj_id},
            success: function(response) {
              window.location.href="/experiment_end";
            },
            error: function(xhr, textStatus, thrownError) {
              alert('An error occurred while trying to save data');
              console.log(thrownError);
            }
          });
},
});
```

The Flask side/the code for `/temp_storage` looked like...

```
@app.route('/temp_storage', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def data_csv_func():
    test_trial_json_obj = request.form['experiment_data']
    subj_id = request.form['webapp_id']
    test_trial_json_obj = json.loads(test_trial_json_obj)
    df_data = pd.DataFrame(test_trial_json_obj)
    csv_name = "app_dir/static/textdata/" + "appid_" + str(subj_id) + ".csv"
    df_data.to_csv(csv_name)
    return "Experiment is over!"

@app.route('/experiment_end', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def show_qualtrics_after_experiment():
    return render_template("end.html")
```

But now I don't want the AJAX call to simply end my experiment. I want my AJAX call to lead to a new webpage within the Flask application that contains a survey, `take_qualtrics.html`. I also need `take_qualtrics.html` to have, at the very least, the `webapp_id` string passed into it (but it would be ideal if I could also pass in the json object for jspsych's data, i.e. `test_trials_json_obj`). This is in order to link survey responses and web app experiment data

I initially just tried replacing the return statement in `data_csv_func()` to `return render_template("take_qualtrics.html", data={"webapp_id":subj_id, "experiment_data":test_trial_json_obj})`, and I deleted/commented out the `windows.href("/experiment_end")` call. I kept the AJAX call as is (the url was still `/temp_storage`), I found that this would execute `data_to_csv()` but the `render_template()` call wouldn't actually redirect my web page to another url.

So it seems like an AJAX call to a Flask function can't actually trigger redirects on the user's side. And I'm not sure how to work around this currently. I want to have some way of loading `take_qualtrics.html` and passing it the webapp id (created in javascript) as an argument.

Comment: You've got a `return` statement before your `render_template()`.

Comment: @PGHE I corrected it. I intended to have that just be a return statement of a string like `"Successful"`. I didn't mean to include a return statement of `render_template()` at all.

Comment: Did you web console spit out an error? Also, could you clarify, did you have a `return render_template` and  `window.location.href="/experiment_end"` at the same time?

Comment: The console has not given any errors. The only time I ever used a `return render_template()` was in the body of the function triggered by `/experiment_end`. That's all that function body contained, only that return statement.

Comment: Can you get a `window.location.href` call to load a dummy/test route that has a `return render_template()` call? Just note your explanation and code don't align, e.g. you want to load `take_survey.html`, but you say your calling `return render_template("take_qualtrics.html`). Different train of thought - on success of you AJAX function do `window.location.href="/survey?'webapp_id=id"` and in that route load your experiment_data and pass that into `render_template`, I think your trying to do too much in the one route, your Posting data to it, then trying to load it again with AJAX? Maybe?

Comment: The html page I am trying to load is `take_qualtrics.html`. `take_survey.html` was a typo, now I have edited my question. a `window.location.href="/experiment_end` where the function for `/experiment_end` only has a `return render_template("take_qualtrics.html)` successfully redirects, but this html page doesn't have the `webapp_id`. `take_window.location.href="/survey?'webapp_id=id"`. This is a query parameter string of some sort, right? I'm not sure, and I actually have been trying to fish for an explanation of whether or not i need to use that.

Comment: The real concern is that the AJAX call has a url parameter of `/temp_storage`. The function for `/temp_storage`, which I have code for in the original question. Its original purpose was to just store the data in a csv... If I change its return statement to `return render_template("take_qualtrics.html")`, nothing happens and the js always goes to the success handler function. I added the `window.location.href(/experiment_end)` statement to load a simple web page called `end.html` to show an end of experiment message.

Comment: @PGHE is this clarifying anything? Cuz if not I'm probably gonna delete this question and make a new one that doesn't have typos. `windows.location.href()` works successfully in the `success` handler function. The issue is that I don't know how to pass the `webapp_id` into the html loaded by `.href()`. I know how to use AJAX to pass data to Flask within an AJAX call, but the AJAX call never redirects to an html page that has the `webapp_id` with it. So I either want to make an AJAX call that forces the page to redirect (and never get to the success handler), or pass parameters into `.href()`

Comment: Yeah I think it does. So your call to `/temp_storage` is successful either with 'render_template' or `Experiment is over`, in that you get a 200 response back, but your AJAX/JS doesn't know what to do with it. You've already got your `webapp_id` in a JS variable `subj_id`, so you could use that to build a URL string with it as a parameter and pass the URL string to `window.location.href`, something like `window.location.href="/experiment_end?webapp_id="+subj_id`. Then you should be able to have your `webapp_id` available in your `experiment_end` route with a `render_template` call.